# Unable to retrieve values from JSON data on iSeries (IBM Midrange)

Tags: json, ibm-midrange

Apologies, in advance, for my lack of knowledge in the area of JSON.

I have created a table called **DSITATR** on iSeries using SQL which has 2 columns -
**UPC# (12char),
ATRDTA (CLOB 4M)**

I then manually inserted a row into the table using the following SQL

**insert into DSITATR values ('123456789991', '
{"PACKS":6, "KG" : 0.367, "DESC" : "Buzz Toy "}')**

I have written a pgm in SQLRPGLE to retrieve the whole CLOB value and it seems to come back as expected:

**{"PACKS":6, "KG" : 0.367, "DESC" : "Buzz Toy "}**

However I cannot seem to be able to extract a value using JSON_VALUE e.g.

**SELECT JSON_VALUE(ATRDTA, '$.DESC') as Description FROM DSITATR**

All I get back is a NULL value.  I'm probably doing something stupid but as far as I can see the JSON is correct.  Any ideas anyone?

Andre Hill

Comment: Can you change the query to the following to get more information?                           
         SELECT JSON_VALUE(ATRDTA, 'strict $.DESC' ERROR ON ERROR) as Description FROM DISTAR

Comment: I tried that in STRSQL and it failed with SQLSTATE 2203A which is SQL/JSON member not found.  Does that mean it's invalid JSON structure or something else?  I tried using the IS JSON predicate and it came back as successful.

Comment: That means something was wrong with your path.  As pointed out below, it looks like a CCSID mismatch between your emulator and the JOB because what the emulator thinks is a '$' is something else.   You can use the query VALUES HEX(CAST('$' AS GRAPHIC(1) CCSID 1200)) to see what the system thinks the value is. The right answer is 0024. If I set my job ccsid to 37 and my emulator code page to 285, I get 00A2, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me...

[image]

Where are you trying to run the `SELECT`?

**EDIT**
I'm also at 7.2, so that's not your issue.

`JSON_VALUE()` [defaults](http://defaults) to `RETURNING CLOB(2G) CCSID 1208`

CCSID 1208 is UTF-8 (Unicode)

If you're using the older Client Access 5250 emulator, The green screen 5250 STRSQL will have problems showing that.

The "Run SQL Scripts" component of either the old Client Access or the current [Access Client Solutions](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions).  Handles unicode just fine as shown in my screenshot.

RPGIV (ILE RPG) handles unicode just fine, but you need to declare that the data is in unicode
`dcl-s myJson varchar(200000) ccsid(1208);`

again trying to display/debug using an old 5250 emulator would be problematic.  The PC based RDi debugger wouldn't have a problem.

Last but not least...you could have the system return the data in your prefered EBCDIC CCISD (37=US English)

```
SELECT 
  JSON_VALUE(ATRDTA, '$.DESC' 
            returning varchar(100) ccsid(37)
            ) as Description 
FROM DSITATR
```

Comment: I tried both in STRSQL and a SQLRPGLE pgm (with DEBUG running).

I have just typed that in as you did above, with the exception of adding a library, and it comes back as NULL using interactive SQL.

Is there something I need to do in SQL to enable JSON?
I should point out we are still running O/S V7.2 by the looks of things.

Comment: @AndreHill see edit ...JSON_VALUE returns unicode data...

Comment: We use ACS as the emulator.  I seem to have resolved it but not sure why it works.
If I change the path in the JSON_VALUE statement from '$.DESC' to '£.DESC' it works fine.  Is this a US v UK thing as I am in the UK.

Comment: Looks like you have a CCSID mismatch between your emulator and your job.   From your emulator, use communcation->configure to see your host code page.  It should match the CCSID of your job as seen by WRKJOB, option 2.

Comment: As per your other reply above, you are quite correct.  My job is CCSID 37 and the emulator is 285 so I do get 00A2 returned as the hex for $ and 0024 for £.  Best check with the tech guys.  Thank you for the information.